# Error while trying to implement face_recognition library: numpy arrary depreciation must add 'dtype=object'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to create a for loop that takes a folder of images and strips the names into a list and then encodes the image to a numpy array in another list. the code works fine until i try to use the compare function of the `face_recognition` library. I have attached the part of the code that is breaking.

ERROR:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)

Code:

```
import cv2 
import face_recognition
import dlib
from imutils import paths
import imutils
import os
import numpy as np


def main():
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    
    knownNames = []
    knownFaces = []
    frameNumber = 0
    faceLocation = []

    imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("dataset"))
    for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
        # extract the person name from the image path
        print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1,
            len(imagePaths)))
        name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

        
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        imageEncoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)

        knownNames.append(name)
        knownFaces.append(imageEncoding)

    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # ***problems start here***
        rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame, model="hog")
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations, model="large")

        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            match = face_recognition.compare_faces(knownFaces, face_encoding, tolerance=0.6)

            if match[0]:
                name = [knownNames][0]

        cv2.imshow('video', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The newest numpy version 1.19 issues this warning (not error) when you try to make an array from a ragged list of lists or arrays.  In  the past numpy just made an object dtype array, without warning. Is there an error as well?  I'd expect the `norm` to have problems with an object dtype array.

Comment: @hpaulj I have just used similar lines of code without the `imagePaths for loop` and it runs correctly no errors. Seems to be an issue when `face_recognition` tries to scan a face as the programme runs without issues when no face is present in the video stream but throws that error when a face is present.